# Apply Webkit Filter to Image within Table Cell on Hover-Over of Cell

Tags: css, filter, css-tables

I'm trying to get an image within a table cell to have a filter applied to it when you hover over the table cell. I'm  not sure if there's a way to this with just CSS.

[EDIT]

```
table.flip td:hover {
     background-color: #510000;
     cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;}

 table.flip td:hover img {
     -webkit-filter: brightness(400%);
     -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     transition: all .5s ease-in-out;}
```

The above is working now other than the fact that mousing out doesn't apply the transition effect again. Mousing in has it fade in, but mousing out has it just blink back to the original state. The above code works on all other images I'm applying this filter to on the site (in terms of a transition in and out).

Is it because it's a table? The table is also within a frame, but the other filtered images are as well. Not sure why it won't transition back.

Comment: table.flip td:hover img {} ... as you already mentioned yourself ... is to do that ... or do i misunderstand your question?

Comment: Ugh, woops, meant to say that didn't work. I'll try again to make sure I didn't mess it up somehow.

Comment: Well, huh, it works now, however the "easy-out" isn't working when I unhover the cell. It just blinks back to the original state. The "ease-in" works fine. Not sure why this would happen.

Comment: ease-in-out means that the transition is not linear ... it is eased-in and eased-out.

Comment: Yes. Transitions work in both directions in general - this has nothing to do with easing.

Comment: Sorry, what I'm saying is that on every other instance of "ease-in-out," it has a transition back to the original state that is the same as the transition to the hover state. However, for whatever reason that isn't happening on these cells. Is it related to the fact that it's a filter applied to a table? Also, the table is inside of a frame. Tried putting the transition effects into the other .flip scripts, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your transition question - have a look at:

http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/transitions-animations

The color transition works like a charm.

EDIT:

Ok now I see your problem:

The transition needs to bee applied to the element itself but not to the hover state.

```
table.flip td {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

table.flip td:hover {
    background-color: #510000;
}

table.flip td img {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

table.flip td:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(400%);
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ULHb4/

Comment: The above would work fine for just the background color, but I'm working with the image as well

Comment: Ah, snap. I had tried that, but not with the right tags. Thanks so much man, that fixed it.